# How to receive advertisement like Axe iAd

Tags: ios, iad

See the following link
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uc5yTo4viwQ. A beautiful video of advertisement using iAd. I am working on a PDF reader application and we are showing some advertisement using google Mediation SDK. My doubt is what should I do to show Add like 'Axe iAdd' where they detect shake, can rotate the angel etc; What should I do to receive that specific Add in my application? Currently I am getting normal advertisement from inMoby. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% about this with Google Mediation, but in iAD there is no way to pick which ads you receive. The best you can do is give iAd keywords for ads you DONT want. Additionally, you don't have to do anything in your app (shake etc) for features within the iAd. These are the responsibilities of the ad's developer and are not dependent on features in your app.

Comment: Can you give me some link or info about how to develop Add. Also do you think that Add was created using HTML5 and it was loaded in a web view ?

Comment: @rakeshNS Yes, iAd producer supports HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript. Here's a link to Apple's iAd page: https://developer.apple.com/iad/ And don't forget to mark my post as correct if it has helped you and answered your question :)

Comment: @rakeshNS Thanks! The funny thing is it's a real attribute of NSNotificationQueue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation on using Apple's iAd advertisements in your app.  There is a lot of information there, more than can be addressed in a single answer.  You may need to have a developer account to access this documentation.

[Using iAd in Your iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/)